# java - How to find the largest weighted edge in a MST?

Tags: java, minimum-spanning-tree

The question is quite simple as per the title.

I have an existing MST, undirected with weighted edges, with V vertexes. Given a starting node and ending node, is there an efficient algorithm that runs in `O(V)` time that returns the largest weight in the MST?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the starting and ending node have to do with the minimum spanning tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modified BFS on your existing MST.
Maintain a global variable maxWeight, and as there won't be any loop here, you can get work done.

P.S. keep track of visited nodes as in BFS.